# How to ensure two docker containers don't process the same file?

Tags: multithreading, docker, docker-swarm

So I have two services A and B in a swarm. A has 5 instances and so does B. They both access files from a common mount. If I put a 100 files in this mount, how do I ensure that the files A and B pick (maybe 50 each) are mutually exclusive i.e the file doesn't get processed twice? Additionally how would i ensure this for two instances of the same service?

Answer (score 0):

With the same methods that you would employ with a shared mount, when there are multiple processes on the same host/or different hosts with access to it. There is little that is unique about containers in this aspect.

You need to apply locks to prevent simultaneous writes. And make sure you always reading the latest data from the volume.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I guess my question wasn't descriptive enough. The data that these containers are accessing doesn't change. And nothing is being written back to these files. Both these containers just have to ensure they're reading or running some method across all 100 files in the mount. But I want to make sure the file is only processed once by any one and only one of the containers. Not by both of them, resulting in the file being processed twice. Not because there is any data corruption but just because I'll be doing the same work twice if both containers process the same file

Comment: How about adding another service with a minimal db so all containers can sync up? Or even simpler: Create a special directory on the volume and every container creates a file with a unique name (generate a random uid) to write filenames the container is currently processing. Or even just a single file? At a certain scale the first solution would become faster / more manageable